# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected identifier "col"

Tags: php

could someone tell me how to fix this error ive been getting this error and i dont know what is wrong with "col" i am using bootstrap so i think there is nothing wrong with it.

```
    function component(){
        $element ="<div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="card text-center">
                        <img src="images/bonsai.jpeg" class="card-img-top">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h3 class="card-title">Aloe Vera</h3>
                                <p class="card-text">Bonsai is the Japanese art of growing and training miniature trees in pots, developed from the traditional Chinese art form of penjing.</p>
                            </div>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Buy Now</button>
                        </div>
                </div>";
        echo "$element";
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do like this:

```
        $element =`<div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="card text-center">
                    <img src="images/bonsai.jpeg" class="card-img-top">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h3 class="card-title">Aloe Vera</h3>
                            <p class="card-text">Bonsai is the Japanese art of growing and training miniature trees in pots, developed from the traditional Chinese art form of penjing.</p>
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Buy Now</button>
                    </div>
            </div>`;
       echo $element;
```

Comment: Your anwer would be much improved if you explained **why** the OP should do what you suggest.